# I have a multi level sidebar navigation menu but would like to keep one button active at a time since they menus overlap each other

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menuitem, submenu, multi-level

[menu overlays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2NzJ.png)

I would like the submenu disappear when I click outside of it.

just one menu at a time.

[One menu open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i83hR.png)

my js code:

```
    function myfunc() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }

    window.onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e.target.matches('dropdown-btn')) {
    var myDropdown = document.getElementById("myDropDown");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
       openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
  }
```

my html code:

```
   <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></button>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

sorry couldn't add the full code because stackoverflow doesn't let me.Those are the sections
I need to write the function on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that with just html and css, no need for JS!

I have created an example with very basic styles, but i think you get the idea.

The main thing is to hide the 2nd level lists (with `.list--level-2 { display: none; }`). Then when you hover on one of the 1st level list items you can the 2nd level list inside it (`.list__item:hover>.list { display: block; }`).

You could then to the same for 3rd, 4th, ... as many level as you need...

```css
.list {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(75 75 75 / 100%);
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list--level-2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% + 1px);
}

.list__item {
  color: white;
  padding: .25rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  position: relative;
}

.list__item:hover>.list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list list--level-1">
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__name">Item 1</span>
    <ul class="list list--level-2">
      <li class="list__item">Item 1 A</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 1 B</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 1 C</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 1 D</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__name">Item 2</span>
    <ul class="list list--level-2">
      <li class="list__item">Item 2 A</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 2 B</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list__item">
    <span class="list__name">Item 3</span>
    <ul class="list list--level-2">
      <li class="list__item">Item 3 A</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 3 B</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 3 C</li>
      <li class="list__item">Item 3 D</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```